# Loop returning very long array even though it is looping 3 times?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

Below I am creating two loops.

Basically it first loops through the randomizer array that holds 4 values.This then randomly generates a number that is between 0 and 3 and chooses one of the values from the randomizer array to console.log back in a random order (For example 2,0,3,1).

The next loop is working at creating wrong answers randomly. If this wrong answer doesn't exist in the allAnswers array it will then push that up to the array.

This then loops and creates a button that will be the users answers that they can choose.

All of this works perfectly. Except that my allAnswers array is returning 13 values when it should only have 4 (1 of which being my pre-determined value of 21).

I need it to create 4 buttons each pulling through an answer with the array position between 0-3 and return those unique values without saying undefined. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong in this instance?

```
var allAnswers = [21],
    randomizer = [0, 1, 2, 3],
    random = 0,
    buttonArea = $("#answerOptions");


for (randomizer, r = randomizer.length; r--; ) {

    random = randomizer.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (r + 1)), 1)[0];
    // console.log(random);

    // Generates 3 random wrong answers
    for(wa = 0 ; wa < 3; wa++) {
        wrongAnswers = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }

    // Pushes wrong answers to array
    if (allAnswers.indexOf(wrongAnswers) === -1) {
      allAnswers.push(wrongAnswers);
    }
    console.log(random);
    input = $('<div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-primary answerButton">'+ allAnswers[random] +'</button></div>');
    input.appendTo(buttonArea); 
}

console.log(allAnswers);
```

EDIT:

Added in new loop that was suggested

```
var goodAnswer = 21,
    allAnswers = [],
    wrongAnswer, 
    wa,
    buttonArea = $("#answerOptions");

for(wa = 0; wa < 4; wa++) {
  do {
    wrongAnswer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  } while(wrongAnswer == goodAnswer || allAnswers.indexOf(wrongAnswer) !== -1);

  allAnswers.push(wrongAnswer);

    input = $('<div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-primary answerButton">'+ allAnswers +'</button></div>');
    input.appendTo(buttonArea); 
}

allAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] = goodAnswer;

console.log(goodAnswer);
console.log(allAnswers);
console.log(wa);
```

Comment: doesn't take long, it takes less than 5ms -> https://jsfiddle.net/zsyuxph7/

Comment: also if you remove the `console.log()` in the middle of your code it takes less than 2ms -> https://jsfiddle.net/zsyuxph7/1/

Comment: I do see cases where that loop is returning values of undefined though? :)

Comment: that's another question, though I think it may be because `randomizer.splice()` returns undefined. also try to define your variables before using them

Comment: Well I wasnt concerned about how long it took to create my array. I was asking why it was returning an array of 13 values over the 4 times its acually going to loop. Cause what I have been trying to figure out is why the array is so large.

Comment: @factor_za When I run your code, `allAnswers` tends to have five elements in it. (This makes sense, since your loop executes 4 times, and odds are each time one answer gets added to the array. Of course, if you happen to pick a random number that's already in `allAnswers`, the array will end up shorter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'wa' loop is useless: it's assigning a random value to 'wrongAnswers' three times. But in the end, you only have a single value.

Another problem is that there is no 'try again' if 'wrongAnswers' doesn't pass the indexOf() condition. Nothing gets inserted on that iteration in that case.

I would recommend a simpler approach: build an array with 4 random wrong answers and replace one of them with the good one.

```
var goodAnswer = 21,
    allAnswers = [],
    wrongAnswer, wa;

for(wa = 0; wa < 4; wa++) {
  do {
    wrongAnswer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  } while(wrongAnswer == goodAnswer || allAnswers.indexOf(wrongAnswer) !== -1);

  allAnswers.push(wrongAnswer);
}

allAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] = goodAnswer;
```

I've omitted the HTML part, but you can do that easily after the array has been built.

EDIT

Or if you really want to process the HTML in the same loop, you may also determine the position of the good answer *before* the loop, so that the nature of each position (wrong or good) is well known from the beginning. Now, you don't have to overwrite one of the wrong answers afterwards and you can safely create the buttons inside the loop.

```
var goodAnswer = 21,
    gaPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4),
    allAnswers = [],
    buttonArea = $("#answerOptions"),
    answer, n;

for(n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
  if(n == gaPosition) {
    answer = goodAnswer;
  }
  else {
    do {
      answer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    } while(answer == goodAnswer || allAnswers.indexOf(answer) !== -1);        
  }
  allAnswers.push(answer);

  input = $('<div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-primary answerButton">'+ answer +'</button></div>');
  input.appendTo(buttonArea); 
}
```

Comment: Okay I see where you are going with this. But how would you then tell it to loop a random array position from the allAnswers array? (I have added an edit to show updated loop you created.)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by looping a random array position from the allAnwsers array. Is there a part of your original code that is missing in mine?

Comment: Also, please see my updated answer if you want to update the HTML inside the main loop. The update in your original post would not work as expected because it doesn't take the 'good answer update' into account. (My first proposition was meant to process the HTML in another loop _after_ the injection of the good answer.)

Comment: So basically what needs to happen is an answer goodAnswer = 21 will be pre-determind. What then needs to happen is I need to generate 3 wrong answers which then get pushed into the array that the goodAnswer would be in. Once this has happened a loop must happen where it generates a number between 0-3. This number will be used to loop allAnswers[randomNumber] in the button generating. That random number must be unique as to not have the same button twice.

Comment: But then again it seems to be doing it randomly itself. Is there a way that I can control or always know which number in the array the correct answer is?

Comment: var correctAnswer = allAnswers.indexOf(21); seemed to work

Comment: In my second version, it's even easier than that: the position of the correct answer is hold in 'gaPosition' from the beginning.

Comment: That is awesome. Just looked now. I would imagine that I could do a comparison to check if the button clicked is equal to that position?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.